# TextField object is not Callable | Python Django & Auth | Default files not working

Tags: python, django, facebook-authentication

I am trying to run manage.py runserver, but am getting stuck with this error.

> "\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\social\apps\django_app\default\models.py",
>   line 30, in 
>       class AbstractUserSocialAuth(models.Model, DjangoUserMixin, on_delete =models.SET_NULL):   File
>   "\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\social\apps\django_app\default\models.py",
>   line 35, in AbstractUserSocialAuth
>       extra_data = JSONField() TypeError: 'TextField' object is not callable

Here is the code

```
class AbstractUserSocialAuth(models.Model, DjangoUserMixin, on_delete =models.SET_NULL):
    """Abstract Social Auth association model"""
    user = models.ForeignKey(USER_MODEL, related_name='social_auth', on_delete =models.SET_NULL)
    provider = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    uid = models.CharField(max_length=UID_LENGTH)
    extra_data = JSONField()
    objects = UserSocialAuthManager()
```

Other than feeding the class on_delete=models.SET_NULL, this is the default code that was installed.

I am using Django 2.1.7, and import JSONField using:

```
from social.apps.django_app.default.fields import JSONField
```

EDIT: Edited to add information / make corrections.

Comment: What's the django version? How do you import `JSONField`?

Comment: Just added the information. Version 2.1.7 though.

Comment: looks like you are trying to use the python-social-auth for django? I think you are using an outdated version of the library. In either case, I think it is flipping to TextField default because you are not using `postgresql` database, in which case it would be safe to try the TextField instead of JSONField and seeing how goes.